# how to apply transform to data displayed in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz, transforms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am getting pointcloud data from different kinects which are facing each other and I am trying to visualize using "rviz". I want to apply a transform (rotate 180 around y-axis) to one of the point clouds and display it, any ideas on how do this? Thank you.
My launch files: [Kinect1_openni_node.launch](http://ideone.com/GWOq8), [Kinect2_openni_node.launch](http://ideone.com/mbdkr), [kinect_frames1.launch](http://ideone.com/7olVB), [kinect_frames2.launch](https://ideone.com/9NvEA)
As you can see in the image the opposite walls are displayed on the same side i.e. w.r.t to their (kinect's) axes.
[image: image description]

UPDATE:
Here's the output of the transforms

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /openni_depth_frame /openni_depth_optical_frame1
At time 1299860886.324
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
rosrun tf tf_echo /openni_depth_frame /openni_depth_optical_frame2
At time 1299860897.873
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.707, -0.001, 0.707, -0.001]
            in RPY [0.000, 1.570, -3.140]
```

Even then I don't see any change, it's the same as the image above. Am I missing any settings in RViz??
Best,
CV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9371/how-to-apply-transform-to-data-displayed-in-rviz?/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say your first kinect has a frame of *openni_camera_1*, and your second kinect has a frame of *openni_camera_2*.

You could make one the child of the other, but I find it cleaner to make them both children of a common virtual frame frame. Let's call that frame *kinect_link*.

You need to [publish a static transform](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher) between the link frame and each kinect. One of the transforms can just be the identity, and the other one will be a 180 y-axis rotation. If you're using launch files, the following lines will create the static publishers:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_link_to_kinect_1" 
args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /kinect_link /openni_camera_1 10" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_link_to_kinect_2" 
args="0 0 0 0 3.14159 0 /kinect_link /openni_camera_2 10" />
```

Next, when you run rviz, simply set the *fixed_frame* filed to *kinect_link*.

Now, the example I gave only accounts for the rotation between the kinects. You probably want to tweak the transforms so that they account for the displacement between them as well.

PS. Are you sure you want a rotation around the y-axis? It might actually be the z-axis.

UPDATE: It looks like getting your two kinects to output in different frames takes a little work. The openni_camera driver allows you to set these parameters: *rgb_frame_id* and *depth_frame_id*. These are set by default to *openni_rgb_optical_frame* and *openni_depth_optical_frame*. However, if you are using the openni_node launch file, it sets these as children to an *openni_camera* frame. So you would have to rewrite the kinect_frames launch file and make two versions of it, one for each kinect

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-11**:
Ivan: my bad those files were old ones. I've uploaded the new ones. it doesn't do anything. All I can see is the axis getting translated every second or so but not the data. Can you chat on gtalk? blueskin.neo@gmail.com .thank you

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-03-11**:
@blueskin: In Kinect2_openni_node.launch, set "rgb_frame_id" to "/openni_rgb_optical_frame2", and "depth_frame_id" to "/openni_depth_optical_frame2. They are set to "1" in both launch files right now, so both kinects are publishing in the same frame (1), and no one is publishing in frame 2.

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-11**:
Ivan: yep, updated two openni launch files. Commands: >> roslaunch openni_camera Kinect1_openni_node.launch , >> roslaunch openni_camera Kinect2_openni_node.launch

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-03-11**:
@blueskin: ok the transforms look good. Can you post your openni launch file as well?

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-11**:
@Ivan: I've modified the launch files and launching appropriate launch files. Links for these files are provided in the question.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-03-11**:
@blueskin: Who is publishing the /openni_depth_frame /openni_depth_optical_frame1 link? Are you using the openni_node.launch file? If so, it calls kinect_frames.launch, which sets those to 0 (probably).

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-11**:
Hey Ivan, I've updated the question with transforms outputs, I don't see any transforms applied to the data. Could you please look at it.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-03-10**:
@blueskin: Yes, you are launching two separate nodes, one for each kinect. Each node should have the depth_frame_id parameter remapped to a unique value. This way you end up with two distinct optical frames. After that, follow the static tf instructions to link them with a common virtual frame

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-10**:
Ivan: I also have separate node launch files. Should I change     to      and 2 respectively? because I don't see any transformations being applied in either case

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-03-10**:
@blueskin: that should work.

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-10**:
Ivan: I was looking exactly into it. I've set both kinects as children of /openni_depth_frame and corresponding frames as given in the links in the question. In RVIZ I've set, fixed frame: /openni_depth_frame & Target frame: ? is it right?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to place a tf frame where you need to place your kinect. Then do either one of these:

1. Change the frame_id field in your point cloud with the new frame name
2. Make your kinect frame a child of the newly created frame

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-10**:
I meant broadcasting a new frame that you use for the kinect you need to rotate. Your problem is that your 2 kinects associate their point clouds with the same frame. check your kinect node, maybe you can set which frame the point cloud will be associated with.

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-10**:
a couple of questions: when you say "place a tf frame" what does that mean? And, how can I change the frame_id without copying the frame and changing frame_id of the copy? Also, I've added an image of my rviz. thank you